# How to verify relational record inserted or not from c# list

Tags: c#, sql, testing

This is testing approach task,

I have `List<Customers>`, let's assume customer list have 10 records and all customer have 3 orders, ( please note in real requirement, there can be *n* records and it may be *x* orders).

```
public class Customers
{
  public int CustomerId {get;set;}
  public int CustomerTableXYZUniqueId {get;set;}
  public List<orders> orders{ get; set; }
}

public class Orders
{
  public int OrderId {get;set;}
  public int CustomerId {get;set;}
  public int OrderTableXYZUniqueId {get;set;}
  public List<orders> orders{ get; set; }
}
```

so total 30 rows will be enter across 2 tables.
    parent Table : customer
    child Table : order

Now in C#, I need to execute a SQL query, which will guarantee me that all 30 rows records have been entered in.

What query should I write in SQL to verify that all records are inserted in 2 tables?

```
parent Table : customer
child Table : orders
```

Maybe something like this, but not sure:

```
select * from customer as poh  join
orders as poL customer.customerId  = orders.customerId 
where customer.CustomerTableXYZUniqueId in ( "172772,18282881,28282818")
and orders.orderTableXYZUniqueId in ('37371', "182882");
```

do you have suggestion please?

Edit1 :

What i am trying to do is, i'm sending List to some POST API call, when API call returning me success, i want to run some kind of sql script via c# which will make sure that records are entered with exact fields value.

here in this example, i have chosen fields property are Customer/OderXYZUniqueId,

So i will read Customer/OderXYZUniqueId values and include in SQL query and see if records are inserted or not.

Edit 2 :

```
var count1 = SQL query with in/join statement.
var count2 = ( how do we calculate the count here)

if(count1 == count2)
{
 // test pass here
}
```

Comment: Did you try to run the query you presented?

Comment: Well the query is a `select`. You need an `insert` query. Do you know what a sql transaction is? -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15, you can `ROLLBACK` in case sth of your query failed.

Comment: I think OP wants to verify if what he insert was right, so he or she already has inserting part.

Comment: @GrayCat, - is it worth to check 'in' sql query? - do we need to validate count from sql row to c# list ?

Comment: @panoskarajohn i will modify of my question in more detail

Answer (score 0):

You can find all records by some unique column:

```
select * from customer where CustomerTableXYZUniqueId in ( "172772,18282881,28282818")
```

and the second:

```
select * from orders 
where orderTableXYZUniqueId in ('37371', "182882");
```

Or try to add some column like `DateCreated` and write C# code when you insert `Date.Now`

Comment: can you please revisit the question, since i have edit it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to ensure there are inserted 30 rows, and all customers are new then a modified version of your query could look like

```
select * from customer as poh 
inner join orders as poL on poh.customerId  = pol.customerId 
where poh.CustomerTableXYZUniqueId in ( '172772','18282881','28282818')
```

assuming your unique id's are strings, otherwise loose the '

this will give you a set with all orders for the three customer id's

if you need to be absolutly sure the order ids are matching as well, then you need to add that criteria as well

```
select * from customer as poh 
inner join orders as poL on poh.customerId  = pol.customerId 
where poh.CustomerTableXYZUniqueId in ( '172772','18282881','28282818')
and pol.orderTableXYZUniqueId in ('37371', '182882')
```

if you just need to ensure 40 rows are inserted in your test, and no one else is inserting data at the same time as your test is running then another approach could be to get a total count before running the test, and compare it with the total amount after.

```
select count(*) from customer as poh 
inner join orders as poL on poh.customerId  = pol.customerId
```

if you want a total count for new customers and orders, then i suggest something like

```
select count(*) as cnt from  from customer as poh 
where poh.CustomerTableXYZUniqueId in ( '172772','18282881','28282818')
union all 
select count(*) as cnt from orders as pol where pol.orderTableXYZUniqueId in ('37371', '182882')
```

Comment: Thanks, i want to make sure the exact records are inserted or not, not just count!

Comment: I see, i've modified the answer to reflect that

Comment: yes, can you please edit your answer, so i can try?

Comment: It is updated, first query gives you 30 rows where customer column Are duplicated for each order

Comment: @mike, the count, we're getting, where we need to compare to that count?, please look at edit 2